# Generating numbers between 1- 6 using the input

Tags: javascript, random

```
 var generate_1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);  

 var ask_user = prompt("Enter the number between 1-6");


 while(ask_user){
  if (generate_1 != ask_user){
  var message = alert("Try one more time");
  }else 
    message = alert("Congratulations");

 }
```

Hi
 I am new to javascript, can you guys help me with the code . Here is the question :
Write Javascript code that does the following :

A) Generates a random number in the range of 1 to 6 then store it within a variable.
B) The program should prompt the user to enter a number from in the range of 1 to 6.q 
C) If the number entered by the user does not match the number generated in point A
display a message inside the browser to encourage the user try one more time.
Otherwise congratulate the user.

PS: Below is an example on how to prompt the user for input

Var name = prompt(“Please enter your name”);
 and the code above.

Comment: Your image is not linked properly. It is recommended to post code as code block or snippet rather than image. You also should explain what attempts you have taken to solve the problem and what is your results.

Comment: You're creating an infinite loop. Also, creating blocking pop-ups in a loop provides bad user experience. Use `input` element and a button, and events for these instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var generate_1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var ask_user = prompt("Enter the number between 1-6");
while(ask_user<=6 && ask_user!=null){
  if (generate_1 != ask_user){
    var message = alert("Try one more time");
    ask_user = prompt("Enter the number between 1-6");
  }else{
    message = alert("Congratulations");
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isCorrect(isThisCorrect) {
    if (isThisCorrect == true) {
        alert("Congratulations");
    } else {
        var generate_1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
        console.log("Number is:" + generate_1);
        var ask_user = prompt("Enter the number between 1-6");
        console.log("User reply" + ask_user);
        if (ask_user == generate_1) {
            isCorrect(true);
        } else {
            isCorrect(false);

        }

    }

}
isCorrect(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the `prompt` statement in the loop and need to add a `break` statement to exit the loop. Something like this:

```js
var generate_1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
while( 1 ){
  var ask_user = prompt("Enter the number between 1-6");
  if (generate_1 != ask_user){
    var message = alert("Try one more time");
  }else{
    message = alert("Congratulations");
    break;
  }
}
```